# Adding AJAX database entry to jQuery

Tags: jquery, mysql, ajax, post, syntax

How do I add AJAX for database entry into this script? It works fine as it is, and I have the php file to go with it, but I keep running into problems with brackets or syntax.

Here is the code that works (take a look at http://jsfiddle.net/myuX3/5/)

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"> </script>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<label for="message_wall">Share your message on the Wall</label>
<input type="text" id="message_wall" name="message_wall" />
<button id="submitbtn" type="submit">Post to wall</button>
<ul id="wall">
</ul>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

$('#submitbtn').click(function() {

    var message_wall = $('#message_wall').val();
    var $d=$("<li>"+message_wall+"</li>").fadeIn(500,function() {
        $('#message_wall').val('');
    });
    $("ul#wall").prepend($d);

});
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

And here is my attempt at ajax. Nothing is added to the database, but everything else works fine:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#submitbtn').click(function() {

    var message_wall = $('#message_wall').val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "insert.php",
        data: {
            'message_wall': message_wall
        },
        success: function() {
            var $d = $("<li>" + message_wall + "</li>").fadeIn(500, function() {
                $('#message_wall').val('');
            });
            $("ul#wall").prepend($d);
        }
    });
});​
});
```

And the accompanying php file:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submitbtn'])){ /*is this the correct syntax?*/
   $message = $_POST['message_wall'];
/* Connection to Database */
$link = mysql_connect("localhost", "*****", "*****") or die("Couldn't make connection.");
@mysql_select_db("*******", $link) or die("Couldn't select database");

/* Remove HTML tag to prevent query injection */
$message = strip_tags($_POST['message_wall']);

mysql_query("INSERT INTO wall (message) VALUES ('$message')");
}


?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change in your accompanying php file

```
<?php
if(!empty($_POST['message_wall'])){ 
/* Connection to Database */
$link = mysql_connect("localhost", "*****", "*****") or die("Couldn't make connection.");
@mysql_select_db("*******", $link) or die("Couldn't select database");

/* Remove HTML tag to prevent query injection */
$message = strip_tags($_POST['message_wall']);

$done = mysql_query("INSERT INTO wall (message) VALUES ('".$message."')");
    if($done){
         echo true;
    }else{
        echo  false;
    }
}
?>
```

regarding firebug error

remove `;` after `success:function() {}`
see this [`fiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/sAyr6/1/)

Comment: great, thanks. I think I still have a problem GETTING to the php file, though. Above I added a little more about information a bug firebug catches each time I run it, saying "missing } after property list".

Comment: still getting the error. Check out a live preview [here](http://innovativeasapple.stevenspiel.com/test.php)

Comment: sorry, i did it, then I still got the same error. I took it off again.

Comment: there is some illegal character in your script  see `â€‹`

Comment: great. got the script working. Turns out I was updating my file locally, but it wasn't connecting to the server... :| still nothing being added to the database, though.

Comment: @mr. this is because `$message` is in comment box. i have updated the code once again

Comment: yeah, I saw that, too. But even if I change the VALUES () to something that isn't a variable, nothing is added. Posting my updated code below:

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13235/discussion-between-diecho-and-mr-musicman)

Answer (score 0):

I think this adjustment will fix your problem (you have an extra semi-colon):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#submitbtn').click(function() {
        var message_wall = $('#message_wall').val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "insert.php",
            data: {
                'message_wall': message_wall
            },
            success: function() {
                var $d = $("<li>" + message_wall + "</li>").fadeIn(500, function() {
                    $('#message_wall').val('');
                });
                $("ul#wall").prepend($d);
            } // ; <-- remove this semicolon 
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
/* Connection to Database */
$link = mysql_connect("localhost", "****", "****") or die("Couldn't make connection.");
@mysql_select_db("****", $link) or die("Couldn't select database");

/* Remove HTML tag to prevent query injection */
$message = strip_tags($_POST['message_wall']);

$done = mysql_query("INSERT INTO wall (message) VALUES ('test')");
if($done){
     echo true;
}else{
    echo  false;
}
}
?>
```

Comment: what is this `if(isset($_POST['submit'])){` ?? change it to `if(!empty($_POST['message_wall'])){ `

Comment: You have been a huge help, diEcho! Thank you very much!